# extend(obj, opts) function?

Tags: java, mongodb, extend, morphia

Is there a way to do something like:

```
db.coll.extend({_id:1,{field1:'test',field2:'test'}}, {deep:true});
```

This would find the object with `_id` 1 in coll (or create one), and then do a `jquery-style` deep extend on that object.

This would be extremely useful when working with static-type languages (e.g., java/morphia)  We could do a `morphia.extend()` call on an existing object without worrying about clobbering existing fields that may have been defined in other applications using the same data store.

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Isn't `jQuery.deep()` doing a (deep) merge of objects and your example is limited to specific attributes?

The best I can think of is Morphia's `merge()`, you can see it in action in https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/master/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/TestDatastoreMerge.java

Comment: Morphia is the exact use-case that is causing problems.  Unfortunately, merge() only handles top-level attributes, so anything deeper in the object gets silently removed if you try to save an object that is defined as a class that doesn't have those attributes.  So, if I load and save an object in morphia, I risk losing fields that the Java code doesn't know about.

Comment: I don't think that's possible and probably against the intent of having entities. What's your scenario? Partial / in progress updates of your entities?